# When is the union of embedded smooth manifolds a smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose we have k embeddings of one single smooth manifold into one other, such that the intersections are manifolds,too. What are sufficient conditions, such that the union of those embeddings is a smooth submanifold in the image manifold?

To be more precise: Suppose we have a manifold M and a manifold N (both smooth). Moreover we have k-many embeddings $f_1: M \rightarrow N$ , $\ldots$, $f_k: M \rightarrow N$ such that the intersections of $f_j(M) \cap f_i(M) \neq \emptyset$ are in general not empty but it is required that 
$f_j(M) \cap f_i(M)$ is itself a submanifold of $N$. Is it possible at all that the union
$\cup f_j(M)$ for all $1 \leq j \leq k$ is a submanifold of N?

Of course it is if all $f_j$'s are equal, but suppose some of them are not. Then in general the union is not a submanifold as we can see for example if we embedded $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ by $f_1(x_1,x_2):=(0,x_1,x_2)$ and $f_2(x_1,x_2):=(x_1,x_2,0)$ and $f_3(x_1,x_2):=(x_1,0,x_3)$. Then the intersections are lines and hence are manifolds by themself, but the union of the images of the $f_j$'s is not a manifold.

The question is: Are there conditions under which the union is a submanifold or not?

Of course one sufficient condition is that there is a $i$ such that $f_i(M)=\cup f_j(M)$ $i \neq j$. So the more interesting situation is, when we have $f_i(M)\neq \cup f_j(M)$ for all $i \neq j$.

Comment: Do you want to assume your manifolds are closed (compact with empty boundary)? 

Comment: I think there are two possible reasons for the union of the embedded sumbanifolds $M_k\subset N$ not being a submanifold of $N$: i) some intersection $M_k\cap M_j$ has lower dimension; ii) some $M_i$ has a (topological) boundary in $N$ that meets another $M_k$.

Comment: This question lacks motivation and could be homework. It seems not suitable for MO to me.

Comment: As a motivation I guess that the spirit of the question is, to provide a criterion to make a submanifold patching together smaller pieces (of course under this respect closed submanifolds are a trivial case) 

Comment: I had a typo in my question... The intersections are manifolds but NOT  images of the preimage manifold. In the situations I have in mind, they are of lower dimension. Moreover nothing like being compact or closed is assumed.

I can't find anything about it and I think this is not trivial or a homework exercise at all. 

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  What does "into one other" mean, for example?   I suspect the answer to your question is "never" provided $k \geq 2$.  But your question is too imprecise to be certain. 

Comment: @Ryan: I agree the question needs some work, but the answer is certainly not "never" - see my answer below.

Comment: @Mirco: I don't understand. The image of an embedding is a submanifold. The intersection of two of these images is a manifold, which (since an embedding is a diffeomorphism onto its image) can be viewed as a submanifold of either of the source manifolds. What am I missing? 

Comment: @Mark: I think the question is so vague that you can make whatever you want out of it.  IMO the question should be rewritten or closed. 

Comment: In general, "what are sufficient conditions" questions are rather unfocused, but at least you seem to have clarified your situation.

Comment: As Anton Lukyanenko points out, the answer to your question is yes and no.  It can be a manifold, it can also not be.  It's not clear there's a useful criterion other than the definition of submanifold. 

Comment: That's more or less what I was writing in my question...

Comment: Do you have any motivation, any case where such a criterion would matter?   There's various fairly artificial situations where you could describe a sufficient condition, I suppose the nicest one would be where all the intersections are manifolds of the same dimension. 

Comment: The situation is given for example in simplicial manifolds. Recall that a simplicial manifold M is a presheaf from the simplex category $\Delta$ into the category of smooth manifolds. There you have smooth degenerarcy maps and when you take a submanifold N[n] of M[n] then each degeneracy $s_j(N[n])$ is a submanifold of M[n+1] and the question is in what particular situation the union of all degeneracies is a submanifold, too

Answer (score 3):

The union will usually not be a manifold. Here are three examples:

1) x (two intersecting lines)

2) 8 (two tangent circles)

3) The [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve), the union of two disjoint embeddings of R.

Based on these, I'm guessing there's no local condition that guarantees the union is a manifold. You probably can't do much better than requiring the manifolds to be closed and disjoint.

Comment: The link leads to nowhere.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment, say for all $i$, $M_i$ is an $m$-dimensional submanifold of $N$.  So in your question, $M_i = f_i(M)$. But the $M_i$'s need not be diffeomorphic for the answer to hold, below.

Further assume that $\overline{M_i} \cap M_j = \overline{M_i \cap M_j} \cap M_j$ for all pairs $i \neq j$, and $M_i \cap M_j$ is also an $m$-dimensional submanifold of $N$ for all $i \neq j$.

Then I claim $\cup_i M_i$ is an $m$-dimensional submanifold of $N$.  The proof is fairly mechanical, basically the closure condition rules out the "topologist's sine curve" example Anton Lukayenko gives.  It ensures that for any point in the union, a chart neighbourhood for an $M_i$ can be restricted to a chart neighbourhood of any overlapping $M_j$ because $M_j$ can't approach from a transverse direction.  The condition that intersections all are $m$-dimensional rules out the figure-8 case, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately the requirement $dim(M_i \cap M_j)=m$ for $dim(M_i)=m$ is not true in the simplicial setting 

Comment: What do you mean?  Certainly it can be true, unless you add some extra hypothesis that nullifies this possibility.  For example, in $\mathbb R^2$ you can take the set $\{(x,y): x > -1, y=0 \}$ together with $\{(x,y): x < 1, y=0 \}$. 

Comment: Its worth noting that *every* closed manifold arises as such a union: just take a finite atlas.

Comment: Maybe its a manifold, iff the coproduct exists as a manifold. This is just an idea I had today and I have to go deeper into it. But maybe someone else knows more...

Comment: @RyanBudney I am guessing that the submanifolds in your answer are intended to be *embedded* submanifolds -- so that the inclusion is a homeomorphism onto its image with the subspace topology. But then can we not construct a counterexample to your claim as follows? Let the ambient manifold be $M=\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $M_1$ be the interval $(-1,1)$ on the $x$-axis, and $M_2$ be the one-dimensional submanifold traced by going along the $x$-axis from $0$ (not included) to $1$, traveling up a little and then back again to the origin, approaching the latter in a direction transverse to the $x$-axis.

Comment: Then $M_1$ and $M_2$ are (I think) both embedded one-dimensional submanifolds, their intersection is the interval $(0,1)$ on the $x$-axis which is again a one-dimensional embedded submanifold, and drawing some figures one sees that the conditions on the closures as written in this answer are satisfied. But the union $M_1 \cup M_2$ is a ["lasso" figure](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AFtgg.png), which is an immersed but not an embedded submanifold of the plane. Have I gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: Indeed, the "claim" is false as Umberto noted.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, I will assume that all manifolds are connected and closed.

An obvious sufficient condition is that the for each pair of embeddings, their images are either disjoint or equal.

To see that this is also necessary, suppose that the two embeddings $f\colon M \hookrightarrow N,\, f'\colon M' \hookrightarrow N$ of copies of $M$ intersect in a submanifold $Q$. Note that $Q = f^{-1}(M') \subseteq M$ can be viewed as a closed submanifold of $M$. This implies that either $Q=M=M'$, or $Q$ has dimension less than that of $M$. In this latter case, the union $f(M)\cup f'(M')$ will not be a submanifold (each point of $Q$ is a double-point singularity of the immersion $f\sqcup f'$).

The same argument extends to disconnected manifolds and shows that the images of each connected component must be pairwise equal or disjoint.

Comment: The intersections are manifolds but NOT images of the preimage manifold. Sorry for that!